# iOS: didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have two `UITableView`in a `viewController`. Both have different tags. `UITableview` with tag 0 is editable and tag 1 is not editable.My problems is when is select row in `UITableview` with tag 1, its not being called. But when i swipe `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is getting called for tag 1.

Here is my code,

```
    - (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
            if (tableView.tag == 0) {
                return YES;
            }
            else if (tableView.tag == 1)
            {
                return NO;
            }
        return NO;
    }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView.tag == 0)
    {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
       {
           //My stuff
       }
    }
    else editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                break;
            case 1:
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapPageSegue" sender:nil];
                break;
            case 2:
                [self closeMenuTable];
                [self  listenMusic];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Any chance you've implemented the willSelectRowAtIndexPath: method? Because if you have there is a chance that you are blocking selection for an index path and didSelect… would not be called.

Comment: @lexaddicted, I have edited my post, please find my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @atreat, i have not implemented  willSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in my code and i have not blocked anywhere in my code.

Comment: So, the problem is that if you select the table with `tag` `1`, no action is taken. How many rows do you have?

Comment: exactly you are right, but when i swipe the row didSelect.. is getting called for tag 1. I have 6 rows in my table for tag 1 and for tag 0 is dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean with *when i swipe the row didSelect..*? Could you improve your question to take into account this? In addition there is no `case` from `3` to `6`..

Comment: The table (tag 1) is not responding for selection of rowa, but when i swipe the row canEditRowAtIndexPath: method is called, in that method i am returning NO and then didSelect.. method is called. Instead of selecting the row, on swipe its getting called.

Comment: It's possible the cells are being partially blocked by a view overlaying them.  That would account for why a portion of the swipe was registering, while touchUps were not.  Try touching different parts of each cell.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments I guess you did not set the `UITableViewDelegate` since `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is a method of that protocol.

Anyway, I would put a breakpoint and do debug. This is the correct way to go deep into problems.

In addition, instead of relying on `tag`s, I would rely on references (by means of IB outlets,  properties or ivars) of the two tables. So for example.

```
if(tableView == self.myFirstTable) {
    // do stuff here
} else {
    // do other stuff here
}
```

Comment: I have set the delegates, but i will try with the IBOutlets and let you know.

Comment: @Logunath You should use debug or `NSLog` to verify if the method is called or not

Comment: @Logunath edit your question and provide how do you set delegates. Thanks